# How to use next link href with condition

Tags: next.js, next-link

I have this code :

```js
<a
  onClick={() => {
    if (fortype === "user") {
      if (rd.track !== null) {
        router.push({
          pathname: `/tracks/${rd.track._id}`,
          query: {
            from: router.asPath,
            at: page,
          },
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (rd.owner !== null) {
        router.push({
          pathname: `/users/${rd.owner._id}`,
          query: {
            from: router.asPath,
            at: page,
          },
        });
      }
    }
  }}
>
  My link
</a>
```

I am trying to replace the `<a>` tag with next/link but it gives me this error:

> Error: Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `function` instead.
> Open your browser's console to view the Component stack trace.

I tried doing it like this :

```js
import Link from "next/link";

<Link
  href={() => {
    if (fortype === "user") {
      if (rd.track !== null) {
        return {
          pathname: `/tracks/${rd.track._id}`,
          query: {
            from: router.asPath,
            at: page,
          },
        };
      }
    } else {
      if (rd.owner !== null) {
        return {
          pathname: `/users/${rd.owner._id}`,
          query: {
            from: router.asPath,
            at: page,
          },
        };
      }
    }
  }}
>
  My link
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is right but the `<Link>` component does not accept functions, 
However if you declare a function then pass its result to `href` it will work:

```js
const myFunction = () => {
//...
}
```

This works because here you are passing the result of a function which is an object, not a function.

```html
<Link
  href={myFunction()}
>
My link
</Linl>
```